# how to solve the error permission denied when ./runInstaller in grid user in oracle linux?

Tags: linux, oracle

I want to install oracle grid infrastructure on oracle linux version 7.9

I did all prerequisites.

I downloaded the grid installation folder from the internet into folder

/home/grid/Downloads

and I need to run the command

```
./runInstaller
```

but I got error

```
bash: ./runInstaller : Permission denied.
```

How to solve this error and start setup please?

Comment: What version of Grid Infrastructure are you installing? Did you install the Oracle Database Pre-Installation RPM?

Comment: @pmdba version 12cR1 yes installed it

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l runInstaller`? Given that this version of Oracle is no longer supported or generally available, from where did you get the download?

Comment: @pmdba the problem from the execute permission its not added before and the command chmod 777 -R solved the issue and ./runinstaller working now thank you

Comment: setting the execute *and write* bits for *all* users is dangerous. also, use of the `-R` option makes all files in the directory and any subdirectories executable and overwrites their original permissions, which could compromise the install.

Comment: @pmdba so better to give execute permission only right ?

Comment: @pmdba can you see I have another issue when I runinstaller the text not appear I post the question and thank you in advance :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284054/why-the-text-not-appearing-in-wizard-when-setup-the-program-in-oracle-linux

Comment: I would have started with just something like `chmod 755 runInstaller` or `chmod 750 runInstaller`, depending on what the original permissions and file ownership were. Just modify the file(s) causing issues and leave the rest alone, without granting excessive permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bash: ./runInstaller : Permission denied.
```

this error means you dont have permission to run the installer check the permission for grid folder and add execute permission :

```
chmod 777 -R /home/grid/Downloads
```

Comment: This is an unsafe permission setting! It allows any user to *overwrite* the files, and may corrupt the original/correct permissions on files to be installed.

Comment: thank you its working now after I complete the setup I will delete this folder

Comment: you are welcome, yes you can give only execute permission to run the setup and I think this server only privileged users can access it.